# What is a _Head object in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Looking at the docs for [DNNLinearCombinedEstimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNLinearCombinedEstimator), I see the first param is a _Head object:

> Args:
>
> head: A _Head object.

I can't find docs about this at all.

What is it?

Answer (score 4):

I found this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py#L53

> Interface for the head/top of a model.
>
> Given logits (or output of a hidden layer), a Head knows how to
>   compute predictions, loss, default metric and export signature.

Reading on, it looks it's just some object from which you can get the predictions, loss, and more of a model, created to simplify model_fn(). And you typically have one head object per model objective.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it will be included with new Head API in some future official version of Tensorflow, right now it is in `contrib` module. You can read more about design here: https://github.com/ewilderj/tensorflow/blob/aea71e8ab41dc18478de019a5b82a66ae76f6e81/rfc/estimator-head.md

Also, from one of the creators, here is small demo: https://youtu.be/4oNdaQk0Qv4?t=11m30s